# wsmlog pushes same data to my REST API every 15 seconds - I only wnat it once

Tags: ibm-datapower

I'm developing a monitoring app for DP (v 10.0.1). Now I want to augment the data I get from the syslog messages by getting payload data by using a wsm log push subacription.

I have a simple testing Java app with an embedded Jersey server to receive the messages as specified in the subscription request.

When I send a test request from Soapui to an mpgw, I get the log message that is pushed from DP, not once, but every 15 seconds until the subsctiiption expires (which I have sent to 60 mins). I only want to receive it once!

I'd be really grateful if someone can help.

BTW, I'm a Java developer not a DP one. Though, I've picked up some DP knowledge over the past few months while writng the code to process the syslog messages.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is here:
https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00006AAyfu/wsmanagement-subscriber-issue?language=en_US

It's a shame this isn't in the IBM docs that desribe how to enable push messages from the wsm log.

Send this xml in your REST server's reponse:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <env:Body>
        <status>received push</status>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```